# Regular Expression to mask given number either from begining or end

Tags: regex

I have a scenario where have to mask two number in return from my application based on the configured regular expression patterns. I have following two numbers and need to mask as shown below.

- 20128569  -->  2012****
- 40953186  -->  ****3186

I need two regular expression patterns to achieve this pattern accordingly using the String.replaceAll(...) or some other possible way.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = "20128569";
    String pattern = "(?<=.{4}).?" ;

    String formattedValue = value.replaceAll(pattern, "*");
    System.out.println(formattedValue);
}
```

**Note:** I need two regular expression patterns in order to mask number as shown above.

However currently i have resolve this issue temporally through the following code. But it is nice if i can resolve this issue through only regular expression.

```
        String maskedAccountNumber = Pattern.compile(aRegexPattern).matcher(aKey).replaceFirst(MASK_CHARACTER);

        StringBuilder maskBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i <= aKey.length() - maskedAccountNumber.length() ; i++){
              maskBuffer.append(MASK_CHARACTER);
        }
        return      maskedAccountNumber.replace(MASK_CHARACTER, maskBuffer.toString());
```

Below are the two regulare expressions i used so far:

1. ^.\d{1,3}
2. .\d{1,3}$

Comment: You should describe the pattern you want to *mask*, if what you want are really two regex patterns, not just the first or last four characters.

Comment: I need two regular expression patterns to mask given number accordingly for the provided regular expression pattern.

Answer (score 0):

That's fairly easy to do, it's still hard to understand under what circumstances do you want which regex.

Either way, `(\d*)\d{4}` and replace it with `$1****`, as seen https://regex101.com/r/uI0zJ6/2

Or `\d{4}(\d*)` and replace with `****$1` https://regex101.com/r/uI0zJ6/3 .

Comment: Actually i want to configure two regular expression patterns in the database and need to mask two numbers like Account Number & Bank sort-code accordinlgy.  So i need to write a method which accept regualr expression pattern and the number and it should return the masked number accordinlgy.

Comment: But using this approach we can't write generic method in order to mask given number using given regular expression pattern. Sometimes my second number could be 6 digit and we have to mask last 4 digits accordingly.